# Determining the datetime of a specific tag on a specific module in CVS

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I need to determine the exact date/time of a specific tag on a specific module in CVS. Can you please help me how can I do this - using eclipse CVS plugin especially? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can. Tags in CVS don't have an existence outside of the files that have that tag, and file either has the tag, or it doesn't.

That's why it's a good idea to put a timestamp *in* the tag name, when you tag it.

Comment: lets say that a file in the module have that specific tag on it with many other tags. then what?

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the same tag to two different files at different times, so trying to find the date/time of a tag is impossible.