# CVS: How to get the date when a tag is created?

Tags: tags, cvs

We have a CVS repository and we create a tag on the active branch whenever a successful build is done.
Is there any way by which I can determine the date when the tag was created?
Looking into the history doesn't helps since it only tells the date-time stamps of the file when it was modified.

Thanks!

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356766/determining-the-datetime-of-a-specific-tag-on-a-specific-module-in-cvs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can easily configure CVS to log all tag-related actions.
In the file '$CVSROOT/CVSROOT/taginfo' you can hook up a
pre-tag script like this:

```
ALL $CVSROOT/CVSROOT/do_tag
```

If this script returns a non-zero exit value, the tag operation will
be aborted.  This allows for syntax checks on the tag names.  You can
also use this hook to send emails, whenever a new release has been
tagged.  To write a history of all tag operations, you need to do
something like this in your do_tag file:

```
#!/bin/sh
TAGHISTORY=~cvs/taghistory.log
echo -n "$(date): user $USER, tag " >> $TAGHISTORY
echo "$*" >> $TAGHISTORY
exit 0
```

---

If you have the history function enabled, you can execute 
the following command:

```
cvs history -a -T
```

It will give you some lines like this, giving you date+time, user, module and tagname of each tagging operation:

```
T 2011-04-02 07:55 +0000 ralph  mylib [testtag:A]
```

For more information check the [cvsbook on history](http://cvsbook.red-bean.com/cvsbook.html#History%20--%20A%20Summary%20Of%20Repository%20Activity)

Comment: +1 for the `history -a -T` but it seems a little flaky. It doesn't show all the tags, even though I know they exist.